# Move constructor hasn't been called

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Here is the code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(T&& val) :
        val(std::make_unique<T>(
            std::forward<T>(val)))
    {
    }

    Foo(Foo&& that) :
        val(std::move(that.val))
    {
        std::cout << *val << std::endl;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<int> val;
};

template<typename T>
void Func(Foo<T>&& val)
{
    std::cout << *val.val << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Foo<int> instance(10);
    Func(std::move(instance));

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that I expect two lines of output here (from my custom move constructor and from 'Func' function), but I get only one. Why?

Comment: Nothing in `Func` needs a move. Compiler may have said, smurf it and ignored you.

Comment: Change `Func` to `auto val2(std::move(val)); std::cout << *val2.val << std::endl;` and you'll see the move construction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Foo<int>` object is not moved at all. `std::move` does not move it; it only makes it available for moving (by casting it to an xvalue). However, since `Func` takes its argument by reference, no `Foo<int>` object is constructed when it is called, so the move constructor is not invoked.